# Каким членом предложения является «вслед» и нужно ли оборот «вслед за остальными» выделять запятыми?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, части-речи

*Он, зашипев от злости, резко дернул рукой, освобождая его, и(,) вслед за остальными(,) оказался во внешнем дворе замка.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Думаю, здесь имеет место комбинированный предлог **вслед за**. Соответственно, он не является членом предложения, а входит в обстоятельственный оборот.

**Большой толковый словарь** ([Грамота.ру](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic?word=%D0%92%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4&all=x))

> **ВСЛЕД.** <...>
> II. ***предлог.** кому-чему.* По направлению, в сторону кого-, чего-л. удаляющегося. Смотреть в. ушедшему поезду. Крикнуть в. беглецу. **<Вслед за** *кем-чем, в зн. предлога.* Следуя за кем-л.; следом за кем-л. *Идти вслед за проводником. Выступить вслед за докладчиком.*

Выделение запятыми сочетания ***вслед за остальными*** будет излишним: первая половина предложения и так достаточно прерывиста, кишит запятыми, а значит, паузами. Если мы продолжим запинаться, вся структура потеряет свободное течение.
Этот обстоятельственный оборот хорошо вписывается без обособления в последнюю часть предложения и по темпу произнесения, и по смыслу.

Comment: В поддержку ответа и в качестве примера (о ненужности запятых): Увидели, что подводят люберецких, с которыми не только встречались, но и враждовали, и даже дрались, **и вслед за остальными** загикали, засвиристели, кто во что горазд. [Анатолий Приставкин. Ночевала тучка золотая (1981)]

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова Приветствую, Римма, спасибо!

Comment: И Вам, Александр, поклон — Новый год ведь (будем надеяться, что поздоровее предыдущего) и Рождество. Добра Вам и хорошего настроения!